# smtplib: Why do the recipients in "To" field receive the mail twice?

Tags: python, sendmail, smtplib

I searched about this quite a lot, but could not fix the issue in my script. So finally, I decided to post it here.

Here's the code snippet:

```
fromaddr = "someValidAddress@xyz.com"
cc = ['SomeEmailAlias@xyz.com']
toaddr = ""
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    toaddrlist = list(toaddr.split(',')) #As sendmail() accepts the list of recipients only in list form.
    toaddrlist += (cc,)
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(cc)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msgHtml = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(msgHtml)
    msg['Subject'] = "Test mail"
    server = "someMailServer.xyz.com"
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server, 25)
    smtp.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrlist, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close() #Close the SMTP server connection.
```

I'm aware and I've ensured that msg['To'] accepts a string value (toaddr), whereas toaddrlist in sendmail() should be a list.

Catch: If I remove the line `toaddrlist += (cc,)`, then the mail does not get delivered twice to the recipients in "To" field, but the mail does not get delivered to the Cc alias.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the line `toaddrlist += (cc,)` is evaluated, the value of `toaddrlist` in your case is :

```
["", ["SomeEmailAlias@xyz.com"]]
```

and it's wrong because `toaddrlist` must be a list of strings not a list containing some lists.

So the solution is to change :

```
 toaddrlist += (cc,)
```

to

```
toaddrlist += cc
```

or the recommended form (the pythonic way) :

```
toaddrlist.extend(cc)
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but none of the fixes seem to be fixing the problem. I'm still getting the email twice. To see what might be going wrong, I printed the values of `toaddr` and `toaddrlist` and they are `somemail@xyz.com` and  `[u'somemail@xyz.com', 'someMailAlias@exchange.xyz.com']` respectively in both the cases.